# Bad Request when updating api in HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, httpwebrequest, webrequest, networkcredentials

I have used Cin 7 Endpoints to Update Order. Here is the link: [Cin7 Update Order](https://api.cin7.com/API/Help/Api/PUT-v1-SalesOrders_loadboms)

and then when calling a api I will have Bad Request error. Here is the code

```
public string UpdateData(string endpoint, Dispatched saleOrder)
        {
            string xmlStringResult = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
                req.Method = "PUT";
                req.ContentType = "application/json";
                req.Credentials = GetCredential(endpoint);

                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(saleOrder);
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
                        {
                            writer.Write(json);
                            writer.Close();
                        }
                    }
                }

                using (var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
                {
                    return resp.StatusDescription + resp.StatusCode;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AppendError(string.Format("UpdateData catch exception: {0}", ex.Message), LogType.System);
            }
            return xmlStringResult;
        }
```

Extracting credential

```
private CredentialCache GetCredential(string url)
        {
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            var credentialCache = new CredentialCache();
            credentialCache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(_cred.Username, _cred.Key));
            return credentialCache;
        }
```

Here is the json data to update

```
{"id":2631912,"dispatchedDate":"2018-05-10T11:49:41.6238207+08:00","trackingCode":"6J7010926112","reference":"255552"}
```

Please help and thank you in advance.

Comment: Read the API documentation carefully and look at the example request carefully. There's a key word just below the "Body Parameters" heading, and it's visible in the request body example.

Comment: I could not see it can you pls tell me

Comment: `[
  {` Look at the first character.

Comment: Well the description says: "**Collection** of SalesOrder" (emphasis mine), and as mjwills says, the request body shows an array of objects, not a single object as you are using.